# how to take whitespace and newline in split function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I must iterate in a string like this:

```
message:    dob cat dog dog
            cat cat
```

Like a multiple separate I need white space and newline (\n) so my function is:

```
message.split(' ,\n').forEach(function(x){
                ...});
```

But this is not work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: maybe you can replace `\n` with a space and then split

Comment: You need this regex: `/\s/gm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this also.

```
message.split(/\s/)
```

Demo : [Click here](http://regexr.com/3cehl)

Comment: The modifiers (`gm`) are not necessary, and the apostrophes (`'`) will render the splitting useless here

Comment: `[ ]` is use as OR operator. You have 1 character only, so `[ ]` is also useless.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use regex:

```
message.split(/[\ \n]/)
```

[] - matches one of characters in this group,

'\ ' - will match single space,

'\n' - will match new line

Comment: Shorter version of this would be 'message.split(/\s/)`, which just splits between all white spaces

Comment: @dr- Your regex only match first space. You need to put `g` modifier in order to apply to all space characters.

Comment: @RyanB This is not how `split` works. You would be right if this was `match`. Test it in your browser and see yourself.

Comment: \s matches also tabs, so as long as you don't need to split around tabs, i would go for '\ \n'.
How \n is useless? It works for me perfectly.